# I can't remove tuxcut, can anyone help me here?

Tags: package-management, uninstall

When I click on remove button, it says I can't remove it because of the following error:

```
installArchives() failed: (Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
[..]
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 202508 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing tuxcut (5.0) ...
rm: cannot remove /usr/bin/run-tuxcut: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package tuxcut (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: arptables: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:
 tuxcut depends on arptables.
Removing arptables (0.0.3.4-1) ...
dpkg: dsniff: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:
 tuxcut depends on dsniff.
Removing dsniff (2.4b1+debian-22.1) ...
Removing libnids1.21 (1.23-2) ...
Removing libnet1:amd64 (1.1.6+dfsg-2ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: wondershaper: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:
 tuxcut depends on wondershaper.
Removing wondershaper (1.1a-6) ...
dpkg: arp-scan: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:
 tuxcut depends on arp-scan; however:
  Package arp-scan is to be removed.
Removing arp-scan (1.8.1-2ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 tuxcut
```

Comment: Could you clarify please? What's the "remove button"? Where do you see it? What happens if your run `sudo apt-get remove tuxcut` from a terminal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
sudo touch /usr/bin/run-tuxcut
sudo apt-get purge tuxcut
```